# UPDATE update_date in table

Tags: php, sql

In my documents table I have a `created_date` field which takes today's time and date and puts it into a field called created_date which works great - I have an additional field on the row called `updated_date` which I need to insert or update when I go back and edit the doc - here is my current method of updating the row:

```
$q = "UPDATE docs SET doc_name='$dn', doc_content='$dc' WHERE doc_id=$id LIMIT 1";
```

I am not sure where the updated_date would live inside of the SQL or if it need to be an insert?

Comment: not clear what you asking

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande Sorry, so currently when I create a post (I call mine documents) it time stamps it for today's time and date and posts that data in a field in the row call `created_date` If I then go back to edit my post/document I want to to insert or update a fields in the row called `updated_date`

Comment: Which database are you using? PostgreSQL? MySQL?

Comment: I am using a MySQL database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to put the timestamp in as part of your query, replace your given query with:

```
UPDATE docs
SET
 doc_name='$dn',
 doc_content='$dc',
 updated_date=now()
WHERE doc_id=$id LIMIT 1
```

If you want it to happen automatically any time someone updates a row in that table, then [create a trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html). You'll need to execute this statement just once, then in future all updates to that table will cause changed rows to get their updated_date set to the current date/time.

```
create trigger docs_trigger_updated after update on docs
for each row set NEW.updated_date = now();
```

You can do other cool stuff in triggers too, including things like preventing queries from changing the created_date etc. Some more info [and examples for triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change field type,

```
ALTER TABLE your_table CHANGE updated_date updated_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

after any update field `updated_date` will be set to current timestamp

Comment: So am I changing what I have above to you suggestion?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand )

Comment: Sorry,could you show me from what I have above what your suggestion would be like?

Comment: if you make your updated_date field like shown above, after any row updates this field will automatically updated to the current timestamp. So you just change the type and let mysql do other stuff

Comment: Im a bit confused? so do I need to replace what I have in my Question to what you have suggested?

Comment: the suggested sql won't work, as defaults only apply to inserts - once a record exists, there is no need for a new default as there's already data there.